# Download and upload speeds

Tags: upload

What are generally upload speeds for enterprise networks and datacenters that host e-commerce sites?  Thanks.

Comment: As already stated, there is no one answer. It will also vary considerably from place to place. The real question then is "how much do you need and who can supply it?".

Answer (score 3):

Most enterprise datacenters have you purchase bandwidth from them as part of the hosting package.  As such you are guaranteed your bandwidth (unlike shared hosting sites where you are more likely sharing it with everyone else) but also are limited to what you've contracted for.  Most will also have bursting agreements where you can use additional bandwidth as needed, for an additional cost.

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty general question. A general answer would be "fast" :-)

To put some real world numbers on it we have a 100 Mb/sec circuit going to our rack at our data center. I have run tests to servers around the internet and I have seen both my download and upload speeds peak out at over 94 Mb/sec.

So to really answer you question, it's whatever speed you need and are willing to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about what you are willing to pay for.  We pay for 100 Megs of bandwidth on a 1 Gig fibre line.  We can use up to 100 Megs for no additional charge, but we can also burst up to 1 Gig for an additional fee.